# how to make Recyclerview works correctly with callback

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit, android-adapter

i have implemented recyclerview and it works fine , i used a call back in BikeAdapter to be able to click every single row of this recycler view but when, i put these lines in OnCreateView the recycler view recycler throw null callback error , and when i delete mAdapter.setCallback(this); the recyclerview became empty

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter); fillData();
        mAdapter = new BikesAdapter(getActivity(), (ArrayList<Bike>) bikes);
        mAdapter.setCallback(this);
```

and when i put these lines inside the filldata() OnResponse method : mAdapter.setCallback(this) is not recognized

```
mAdapter.setCallback(this);
```

if i want to display my recycler view without problems i have to delete mAdapter.setCallback(this);
mAdapter = new BikesAdapter(getActivity(), (ArrayList) bikes);
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
inside the fillData to get the response at the right time

//my adapter code

```
package com.example.miniprojetandroid.adapters;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.R;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.models.Bike;


public class BikesAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BikesAdapter.BikesViewHolder> {

    private final ArrayList<Bike> bikes;
    private Context mContext;
    private Callback mCallback;

public BikesAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Bike> bikes) {
        this.mContext = mContext ;
        this.bikes = bikes;
        }

@NonNull
@Override
public BikesAdapter.BikesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View mItemView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.bike_list_item, parent, false);
        return new BikesViewHolder(mItemView, this);
        }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BikesAdapter.BikesViewHolder holder, int position) {
final Bike singleItem = bikes.get(position);

        holder.BikeName.setText(singleItem.getModel());
        holder.BikeImage.setBackgroundResource(singleItem.getImage());
        holder.bikeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCallback.onItemClicked(singleItem);
            }
        });
        holder.BikeImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext,singleItem.getModel(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        });
        }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
        return bikes.size();
        }

public class BikesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public final TextView BikeName;
    public final ImageView BikeImage;
    public final Button bikeView;
    final BikesAdapter mAdapter;

    public BikesViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, BikesAdapter mAdapter) {
        super(itemView);
        this.BikeName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bikeName);
        this.BikeImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bikeImage);
        this.bikeView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_view);
        this.mAdapter = mAdapter;
    }
}


    public void setCallback(Callback callback) {
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    public interface Callback {
        void onItemClicked(Bike bike);
    }

}
```

//my fragment that contains the recyclerview

```
    package com.example.miniprojetandroid.ui.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.miniprojetandroid.Retrofit.BikeService;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.Retrofit.RetrofitClient;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.Retrofit.UserService;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.adapters.BikesAdapter;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.models.Bike;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.models.User;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class FragmentOne extends Fragment implements BikesAdapter.Callback{

    private BikeService apiService;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<Bike> bikes = new ArrayList<Bike>();
    private  BikesAdapter mAdapter;
    List<Bike> result = new ArrayList<Bike>();




    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container,false);

        recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_bikes);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),
                LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

        apiService = RetrofitClient.getClient().create(BikeService.class);
        fillData();
        mAdapter.setCallback(this);
        return rootView;
    }


    public void fillData(){


        Call<List<Bike>> call = apiService.getBikes();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Bike>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Bike>> call, Response<List<Bike>> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    bikes.addAll(response.body());
                    for(Bike bike: bikes){
                        bike.setImage(R.drawable.ruebike);
                    }
                    Log.e("Bike LIST", bikes.toString());
                    mAdapter = new BikesAdapter(getActivity(), (ArrayList<Bike>) bikes);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


                    //listView.setAdapter(new UserAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_user, list));
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Bike>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("ERROR: ", t.getMessage());
            }
        });




        /*bikes.add(new Bike(1,"ECO", "RTT" , "44", R.drawable.ruebike ));
        bikes.add(new Bike(2,"AAA", "RTT" , "33",  R.drawable.ruebike ));
        bikes.add(new Bike(3,"BBB", "RUE" , "11",  R.drawable.ruebike ));
        bikes.add(new Bike(4,"EEE", "SPORT" , "25",  R.drawable.ruebike ));
        bikes.add(new Bike(5,"CCC", "SPORT" , "77", R.drawable.ruebike ));
        Log.e("USERS LIST", bikes.toString());*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(Bike bike) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("bike_id",bike.getId());
        bundle.putString("model", bike.getModel());
        bundle.putString("type", bike.getType());
        bundle.putString("price", bike.getPrice());
        bundle.putInt("image", bike.getImage());
        DetailsFragment f = new DetailsFragment();
        f.setArguments(bundle);
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragmentsContainer, f )
                .commit();
    }




}
```

What i am trying to do is two things:
1/ make my fragment recyclerview works with filldata with the call back method(for idea Log.e show that this method works fine)
2/ to make sure that when i click an item of the recycler view , i pass the selected bike to a thired fragmend (DetailsFragment)

Errors:  the recycler view is empty when i delete the callback and it throw null exception when i use it

help me pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the method fillData is not executing immediately because it contain network operation so it work on background thread , so when you call setCallback , the mAdapter will not be initialized yet , so i suggest to initialize mAdapter and call setAdapter inside onCreate instead of onResponse method, and you can pass the array to the constructor as null ,and inside onResponse you can pass the bikes arrayList by setter method and inside this method (the setter method) after assigning the list add "notifyDataSetChanged();"

so your adapter will look like :

```
package com.example.miniprojetandroid.adapters;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.R;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.models.Bike;


public class BikesAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BikesAdapter.BikesViewHolder> {

    private final ArrayList<Bike> bikes;
    private Context mContext;
    private Callback mCallback;

public BikesAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Bike> bikes) {
        this.mContext = mContext ;
        this.bikes = bikes;
        }
public setBikesList(ArrayList<Bike> bikes){
this.bikes=bikes;
notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@NonNull
@Override
public BikesAdapter.BikesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View mItemView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.bike_list_item, parent, false);
        return new BikesViewHolder(mItemView, this);
        }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BikesAdapter.BikesViewHolder holder, int position) {
final Bike singleItem = bikes.get(position);

        holder.BikeName.setText(singleItem.getModel());
        holder.BikeImage.setBackgroundResource(singleItem.getImage());
        holder.bikeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCallback.onItemClicked(singleItem);
            }
        });
        holder.BikeImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext,singleItem.getModel(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        });
        }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
        return bikes.size();
        }

public class BikesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public final TextView BikeName;
    public final ImageView BikeImage;
    public final Button bikeView;
    final BikesAdapter mAdapter;

    public BikesViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, BikesAdapter mAdapter) {
        super(itemView);
        this.BikeName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bikeName);
        this.BikeImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bikeImage);
        this.bikeView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_view);
        this.mAdapter = mAdapter;
    }
}


    public void setCallback(Callback callback) {
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    public interface Callback {
        void onItemClicked(Bike bike);
    }

}
```

and your fragment :

```
package com.example.miniprojetandroid.ui.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.miniprojetandroid.Retrofit.BikeService;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.Retrofit.RetrofitClient;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.Retrofit.UserService;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.adapters.BikesAdapter;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.models.Bike;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.models.User;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class FragmentOne extends Fragment implements BikesAdapter.Callback{

    private BikeService apiService;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<Bike> bikes = new ArrayList<Bike>();
    private  BikesAdapter mAdapter;
    List<Bike> result = new ArrayList<Bike>();




    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container,false);

        recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_bikes);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),
                LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

        apiService = RetrofitClient.getClient().create(BikeService.class);
        fillData();
        mAdapter = new BikesAdapter(getActivity(),null);
        mAdapter.setCallback(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
       
        return rootView;
    }


    public void fillData(){


        Call<List<Bike>> call = apiService.getBikes();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Bike>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Bike>> call, Response<List<Bike>> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    bikes.addAll(response.body());
                    for(Bike bike: bikes){
                        bike.setImage(R.drawable.ruebike);
                    }
                    Log.e("Bike LIST", bikes.toString());
                    mAdapter.setBikesList(bikes);


                    //listView.setAdapter(new UserAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_user, list));
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Bike>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("ERROR: ", t.getMessage());
            }
        });




        /*bikes.add(new Bike(1,"ECO", "RTT" , "44", R.drawable.ruebike ));
        bikes.add(new Bike(2,"AAA", "RTT" , "33",  R.drawable.ruebike ));
        bikes.add(new Bike(3,"BBB", "RUE" , "11",  R.drawable.ruebike ));
        bikes.add(new Bike(4,"EEE", "SPORT" , "25",  R.drawable.ruebike ));
        bikes.add(new Bike(5,"CCC", "SPORT" , "77", R.drawable.ruebike ));
        Log.e("USERS LIST", bikes.toString());*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(Bike bike) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("bike_id",bike.getId());
        bundle.putString("model", bike.getModel());
        bundle.putString("type", bike.getType());
        bundle.putString("price", bike.getPrice());
        bundle.putInt("image", bike.getImage());
        DetailsFragment f = new DetailsFragment();
        f.setArguments(bundle);
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragmentsContainer, f )
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: i do not understand u good brother , please i am lost fully , can you show me exactly how to do it? please i am at stake , tomorrow the teatcher need to see it work